# Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::Atividades_list() must be an instance of App\Atividade_de_Risco, array given

Tags: php, laravel

I try to pass a model variable as parameter but this error pop up

> Argument 1 passed to
> App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::Atividades_list() must be an
> instance of App\Atividade_de_Risco, array given

```
public function Atividades_list(Atividade_de_Risco $atividades){
        //$atividades = Atividade_de_Risco::all();
        return  Datatables::of($atividades)->make(true);

    }

    public function Atividades(Request $request){
        //dd($request->all());
        $atividades = Atividade_de_Risco::all();
        $atividades_ [] = new Atividade_de_Risco;
        
        $user_atvs = Usuario_atividade::all();
        $id = Auth()->user()->id;
        $i = 0;
        
        $this->Atividades_list($atividades_);
        
        //
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass to Atividades_list function param with Atividade_de_Risco instance but you pass array variable

```php
    public function Atividades(Request $request){
        //dd($request->all());
        $atividades = Atividade_de_Risco::all();
        $atividades_ = new Atividade_de_Risco;
        
        $user_atvs = Usuario_atividade::all();
        $id = Auth()->user()->id;
        $i = 0;
        
        $this->Atividades_list($atividades_);
```

Please remove [] after $atividades_ variable